# How to write biology coupled reactions

Tags: equations, chemfig, chemistry

Good day LaTeX users. How best can I write a coupled reaction like the one shown on the attached image.

I wish I can include a shorted example, but I do not know where to start. Thank you very much

[image: coupled reaction]

Comment: The chemfig package and its - U> arrow type should help getting you started..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of `chemfig`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
  glucose \arrow{-U>[2 ATP][2 ADP][][0.5][60]} 2 PGAL
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly, what I wanted